# JSONDecodeError when looping through SEC indices

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Something strange keeps happening when I try to scrape SEC filings from the web. The web scraping code I've executed in Python 3 loops through a list of CIKs (a unique filing ID for companies). This is where the code breaks (early in the code):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

base_url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/'

for cik_number in ciks['public_ciks']:

    url = f'{base_url}{cik_number}/index.json'
    response = requests.get(url)

    # Parse the response
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

    # **This is where the error occurs**
    decoded_content = response.json()

    JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

When I ran this command the other day, it worked just fine. Today, not only does this command keep throwing an error, but it happens at different parts of the loop: sometimes it's the 1st url, sometimes the 5h, the 8th, etc., with no consistency. When I isolate those URLs and perform this command for a single instance, there's never an error, making this issue of mine ever stranger. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: There's probably something wrong with some of the documents you're trying to retrieve, you could be getting an error message formatted as HTML, instead of the JSON you're expecting. You should print out response.text before attempting to convert to json.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
 decoded_content = response.json()
```

You have to import the json module then you should use:

```
decoded_content = json.loads(response.text, encoding="utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `strict` attribute as `False`
Try this:

```
decoded_content = json.loads(response.text, encoding="utf-8", strict=False)
```